# WooCommerce - logged in/non-logged in content cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce

We want to have a page that displays different content based on whether a user is logged in. If they are logged in, they should be able see their private content. If they are not logged in, there should simply be just a link to a login page. Once they log in, they can navigate back to the original page.

The problem is that when they re-visit the original page after logging in, it's essentially like the page is cached as it still displays the content as if the user is not logged in. However if you refresh the page, it then loads the right content.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(!user_can($current_user, "custom_user_role")){ ?>
    <p>You are not permitted to view this page. Please <a href="/my-account">log in or sign up</a>.</p><?php
}else{ ?>
    <p>You are logged in</p><?php
}
```

I have tested with a new, blank WordPress/WooCommerce install, and the same issues occured.

We aren't using any caching plugins (as this is still very much in development).

I have had the same result in Chrome and Firefox, across various machines.

The closest I have come to an answer was by testing within Chrome, utilising the "Disable cache" option, and had the expected outcome, i.e; the content loaded correctly without needing the refresh.

Is there a simple answer to this?

If not... is there a way to force a local cache refresh when a user logs in?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue